# Почему в командах Laravel 10 метод handle(): void?

Tags: php, laravel

Почему в методе handle прописан ожидаемый тип void, а не int?

Понятней же когда handle возвращает число

- 0 - всё хорошо
- 1 - всё плохо
- 2 - всё плохо
  ...

```
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     */
    public function handle(): void
    {
     //...
    }
```

Comment: Если всё плохо, то приложение должно генерировать исключение. И тогда никакие `return всё плохо` в принципе не понадобятся. А если всё отработало - то значит всё хорошо

Comment: *"Понятней же когда возвращает число"* --- нет не понятнее. Если только наизусть это не заучить. А если будет возвращать 3456 или 23234 - будете помнить все комбинации? Такая магия совершенно никому не понятна

Answer (score 1):

Все всё равно пишут свою информацию выполнения, чтобы было понятно из консоли. Скорее всего поэтому Laravel перестал генерировать код с возвратом конкретного числа.

Если ничего не передано, команда под капотом всё равно вернёт 0. Поэтому если требуется, можете передать свои значения и заменить тип на int:

```
return Command::SUCCESS; // 0
return Command::FAILURE; // 1
return Command::INVALID; // 2
```

Comment: *"можете передать свои значения и заменить тип на int:"* --- не получится. Будет 500 ошибка с текстом `Fatal error: Declaration of Class2::handle(): int must be compatible with Class1::handle(): void`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не будет, это не наследуемый метод класса. Под капотом метод резолвится `$method = method_exists($this, 'handle') ? 'handle' : '__invoke'; ... return (int) $this->laravel->call([$this, $method]);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский void приводит к 0. Такое ощущение что сделано для ленивых (забывчивых)

Comment: @ZigZag вообще, как написал Владимир выше, сам метод вызывается из execute вон тем интересным способом https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/master/Command.php#L209    ..... моё ИМХО - эти 0, 1,2 не нужны [из-за ентого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1562878/#comment2815240_1562878)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю дело тут в следовании паттерну CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation) — это архитектурный паттерн, который предлагает разделить операции записи и чтения данных в приложении на две отдельные ветки.

Команды - для insert/update/delete, запросы - на select, соответственно

Команды - меняют состояние системы и не возваращют никаких данных, запросы, наоборот, не меняют состояние системы и возвращают какие-то данные наружу.

Плюсы такого подхода - в возможности асинхронности команд. Например, нужно загрузить видео. Пользователь выбирает его на компе, нажимает "загрузить" и может дальше спокойно гулять по сайту. В какой-то момент (не важно когда), может прилететь уведомление, что "видео загружено, можете посмотреть". Важно понять, что само это сообщение будет показано как следствие подписки на событие, а не как следствие возвращаемого ответа от команды.

Более подробно про CQRS читайте в интернете))